# My webpage display &#039; and not '

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php script which return a JSON, and a js function which parse this JSON. In my php I did a htmlspecialchars but when I display value in my webpage `&#039;` isn't replace by ' same for `&quot;`
any idea ?

Comment: How are you putting the JSON result into the page?

Comment: Why are you calling `htmlspecialchars()` in the first place? The usual reason for that is so that you see the literal HTML, instead of getting it parsed.

Comment: If I don't use I have an object and not a value in my JSON I don't know why but the htmlspecialchars solve the problem then I use it

Comment: it sounds like there's a problem with how you're creating the JSON. `json_encode()` shouldn't create an object instead of a value. You REALLY need to show your code for us to help you.

Comment: I just cast to string :$this->description = (string)$description; to solve my problem, and remove the htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are seeing `&#039;` on the page, you have probably double-encoded your string somewhere along the lines.

Encoding the string the first time changes `'` to `&#039;`.

Encoding the string a second time changes `&#039;` to `&amp;#039;`.

The result of this is that you see the code, not the char - as the web page converts the `&amp;` to `&` visually, and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Use `html_entity_decode()` with `ENT_QUOTES`

```
$string = "test &#039;";
echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

---

Output:

```
test '
```

---

DEMO
http://ideone.com/pZdJOa

---

read more about [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

Answer (score 0):

When you do use `htmlspecialchars` "  "'" (single quote) becomes `'&#039;'` (or `&apos;`) "

Read the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: But if he adds that to his HTML, it should be rendered properly. The problem is with how he's adding it to the HTML, which he hasn't shown.